# How to find the correlation coefficient of a greyscale image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, correlation

In order to find the correlation between two adjacent pixels (horizontal, vertical and diagonal), I have randomly selected `3000` pairs of adjacent pixels from the original and encrypted images. I used the inbuilt MATLAB function `corrcoef` but I'm not getting the result. Do I need to find the mean, variance and covariance of the pixels before calculating the correlation coefficient?If I do where do I use it in the function? This function doesnt seem to use any of the values. I used the following code to calculate for horizontally adjacent pixels

```
m1 = A(:,1:end-1,1);  %# All rows and columns 1 through 255 
n1 = A(:,2:end,1);    %# All rows and columns 2 through 256 
                      % A is the original image
randIndex1 = randperm(numel(m1));  %# A random permutation of the integers
                                   %#   from 1 to numel(m1)
randIndex1 = randIndex1(1:3000);   %# Pick the first 3000 indices
m1Rand = m1(randIndex1);            %# 3000 random values from m1
n1Rand = n1(randIndex1);            %# The corresponding 3000 values from n1 

r_mn1 = corrcoef(m1Rand(:),n1Rand(:)); disp('r_mn1=');disp(r_mn1);
```

I do have the formulas for calculating mean, variance, covariance and correlation coefficient.I want to know whether the inbuilt function can be used in this case or should I calculate using the formulas?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "but I'm not getting the result."? Is there no output?

Comment: @bdecaf really sorry for the information i provided in the previous comment.I dont get the output at all. i mean i shoud've got the value of correlation coefficient after computing for the 3000 pairs. I want to know whether the usage of this function 'corrcoef' is correct. do i need to calculate the mean , variance and covariance for calculating the correlation coefficient. If so where do i use this in the code. I do have formulas for mean, variance, covariance and correlation coefficient but i thght of using the inbuilt matlab function corrcoef.

Comment: no problem. To the question: No corrcoef takes care of this. I still don't understand the specific problem - but often one messes up the orientation of matrices. Maybe try to transpose the inputs like `corrcoef(m1Rand(:)',n1Rand(:)')`

Comment: @Abirami Anbalagan Just tried your code with A = randi(256,300,300) - 1, it works (displays correlation matrix).

Comment: @Kostya thank u. i did get the result by changing the orinetation as suggested by bdecaf.

Comment: maybe try r_mn1 =corrcoef(double(m1Rand(:)),double(n1Rand(:)));